# Exporting graphdef protobuf during training of inception model

Tags: tensorflow

Has anyone incorporated the ability to save a graphdef protobuf along with each checkpoint in the inception-v3 model?

Lively discussions at https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/616 provided some solutions to export graph protobufs, but I cannot get any of them working using the inception training model (inception_train.py).

I am trying to implement graph.util.convery_variables_to_constants, but I am failing to capture trainable variables, as I always get assertion errors: [variable] is not in graph. I am using output names from tensorboard, which may be incorrect procedure.

Any solutions to this issue would definitely be of interest to the general community, not only for learning but deployment.

Thanks!